# Sniffing lowspeed CAN bus with highspeed device

Tags: safety, automotive, can, bus, risk-analysis

Is it possible to use a highspeed (HS) CAN interface for listening to a lowspeed (LS) CAN bus? If so - Is it in any way questionable to do so in a real world car or moped?

As far as I know, LS CAN supports failsafe operation when one signal is broken. I assume, this will not be supported by a HS transceiver.

In my application, I can insure (by means of hard- and firmware measures) that my device is not writing messages to the CAN bus.

So, which risks should I keep in mind when listening on a LS CAN bus?

Comment: I'd make/buy an adapter with two transceivers that converts from one physical bus to the other. Data link layer should be identical, just not the signal levels.

Answer (score 2):

High-speed CAN (ISO 11898-2) and Low-speed CAN (ISO 11898-3) are different in physical layer.
They are not electrically similar. I do not recommend using a HS transceiver on a LS bus.

High-speed CAN:
[image]

Low-speed CAN:
[image]

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus))

Comment: Would you see a risk that a HS transceiver interferes with the LS-bus traffic? I only want to sniff, not transmit.